# Save nethogs speed output to file

Tags: ubuntu, awk

I want to log my download speeds using nethogs. I've tried the following:

```
nethogs -t wlo1 | awk '/firefox/{ print $3}'> speedTest.txt
```

However, the output file turns out to be empty. I've already assured that I can save to a file using this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2126456/how-to-output-awk-result-to-file). And I've looked at the code in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20702980/capture-nethogs-output-in-log-file), but it does not exactly do what I want.

I do get DL speed output in my terminal when I try:

```
nethogs -t wlo1 | awk '/firefox/{ print $3}'
```

-- EDIT --
With the suggestion below

```
(nethogs -t wlo1 | awk '/firefox/{ print $3}) &> speedTest.txt
```

I get the output in the file speedTest.txt:

"Waiting for first packet to arrive (see sourceforge.net bug 1019381)"

which is the standard output from nethogs everytime I run it. The rest of the file is empty.

When I just run `nethogs -t wlo1 | awk '/firefox/{ print $3}'`, I get something like

> "Waiting for first packet to arrive (see sourceforge.net bug 1019381)"
>
> 102.8
>
> 248.7
>
> 318.2

etc, etc.

Comment: probably it's using stderr. use `2>&1` or `&>`

Comment: the file remains empty with both suggestions

Comment: try `(nethogs -t wlo1 | awk '/firefox/{ print $3}) &> speedTest.txt`

Comment: I only get the standard output: "Waiting for first packet to arrive (see sourceforge.net bug 1019381)". Still no speed data.

Comment: @MichaelDeSanta can you give a sample of your output?

Comment: try this: `nethogs -t wlo1 2>&1 | awk '/firefox/{print $3}'> speedTest.txt`

Comment: it worked! many thanks, you saved me from a lot of unnecessary pre-processing work :)

Answer (score 0):

This worked, base on webb's answers:

```
nethogs -t wlo1 2>&1 | awk '/firefox/{print $3}'> speedTest.txt
```